# Why doesn't React app fetch images from AWS S3 Bucket?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, fetch

I have a React app to show products list.
[image]

As you can see, the product images are from AWS S3 bucket which is fully public.

[image]

And the bucket policy is:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::productmanageapp/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": "productmanageapp"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

At this moment, I tried to fetch an image from the bucket and use it as blob type, because I was needing to show an image as well as upload it.

But it is weird, I couldn't fetch images even fetching the same way to the product list.

```
const response = await fetch(product.image, {headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization" }});
```

[image: A product image url looks like]

If I hit the product image url, it opens the image in the browser successfully without downloading.

The image file has the following meta tags:

[image]

Why does fetching the product images work or not work?

CORS error doesn't make any sense, because the same way works well in another page.

**UPDATE**: CORS setup:

[image]

And I tried to use method `HEAD` only. It is getting the CORS error as well.

```
fetch(url, { method: 'HEAD' })
```

I am using chrome browser.
[image]

Comment: have you setup CORS on S3 ?

Comment: @BaluVyamajala Could you check my last *update*? You mean that one?

Comment: can you remove Access control headers from the request, we will get them from s3, some times, it also causes issues.

Comment: @BaluVyamajala, I removed the headers from the request, but it is still not working.